# Type error in getting route params within nested navigator using Typescript [react-navigation v6]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

Having a navigation type definition as bellow, when I navigate from e.g `AOne` to `BTwo` with `id:99`  the console log of `props.route.params` shows correct info. But `props.route.params.id` throws type error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.route.params.id')

```js
    // navigation related imports in all components 
    import {BottomTabScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
    import {CompositeScreenProps, NavigatorScreenParams} from '@react-navigation/core';
    import {StackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/stack';

    // type defenitions
    export type StackOneParams = {
      AOne:undefined,
      BOne: undefined,
      // some other screens
    };
    export type StackTwoParams = {
      ATwo: undefined;
      BTwo:{id:number};
      // some other screens
    };
    
    export type TabParams = {
      StackOne: NavigatorScreenParams<StackOneParams>;
      StackTwo: NavigatorScreenParams<StackTwoParams>;
    // ... some other stacks each represent a tab 
    };

    export type RootParamList = {
       ROne: undefined;  // these screens should stand alone and not blong to any tab
       RTwo: undefined;
       Tabs: NavigatorScreenParams<TabParams>
    }

    // navigation from AOne to BTwo
      props.navigation.navigate('Tabs', {
         screen: 'StackTwo',
         params: {screen: 'BTwo', params: {id: 99}}
     }); // this part give correct auto complete hints in VSCode and no compilation error

 // BTwo component (screen)
//--------------------------------
    type Props = CompositeScreenProps<
  StackScreenProps<RootParamList, 'Tabs'>,
  CompositeScreenProps<
    BottomTabScreenProps<TabPrams, 'StackTwo'>,
    StackScreenProps<StackTwoParams, 'BTwo'>
  >
>;// using CompositeScreenProps to be able to navigate to screens in another tabs
// otherwise just `type Props=StackScreenProps<StackTwoParams, 'BTwo'>` works fine but cannot navigate to other tabs


    const BTwo:React.FC<Props> = (props) =>{
    console.log(props.route.params)// the log shows {id:23} 
    // but props.route.params.id gives error and also no auto completion hint 
       return(...)
    }
```

- **is this the correct way to define screen props for a specific screen, like what I have in BTwo screen? or the sequence of the composition should be different?**

most of the examples ([and the official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/typescript/#combining-navigation-props)) show the most simple composition where the target screen is not even in second level of nesting (in the official doc `profile` is not really in nested bottom tabs)

How should I solve the type error in this case?

the image shows the VSCode auto-complete suggestions

[image]

Comment: I have found a solution to use `CompositeScreenProps` and clarified my answer in case you ever need this again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Solution using CompositeScreenProps

My other explanations were not quite accurate. The way you have defined the `CompositeScreenProp` is not correct. Here is the correct way to implement this.

```js
type ScreenProps = CompositeScreenProps<
  StackScreenProps<StackTwoParams, "BTwo">,
  CompositeScreenProps<
    BottomTabScreenProps<TabParams, "StackTwo">, 
    StackScreenProps<RootParamList>
  >
>
```

The first parameter of `CompositeScreenProps` contains the type of the navigator that *owns the screen*. In this case `BTwo` is owned by `StackTwo` and this determines the primary navigator, which is a `Stack`.

The above yields to the correct types as well.

```js
const BTwo = (props: ScreenProps) => {
  return <></>
}
```

[image]

[image]

---

### Solution using separate types for navigation and route

We can type the navigation object and the route object separately as follows.

```js
type NavigationProps = CompositeNavigationProp<
  StackNavigationProp<StackTwoParams, "BTwo">,
  CompositeNavigationProp<
    BottomTabNavigationProp<TabParams, "StackTwo">, 
    StackNavigationProp<RootParamList>
  >
>

type ScreenPropsA = {
  navigation: NavigationProps
  route: RouteProp<StackTwoParams, "BTwo">
}
```

Notice the usage of `CompositeNavigationProp` and `RouteProp` here.

Then, use it as follows.

```js
const BTwo = ({ route, navigation }: ScreenProps) => {

  return <></>
}
```

Both, `route` and `navigation` are now correctly typed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, well thanks, but it does not answer my question. I want to have both `navigation` and `route` in props , but with using only `StackScreenProps`then we loose `navigation.navigate` ability to navigate to other tabs. This fact was mentioned in inline comments of the question

Comment: regarding the navigate part, where you have written `Clearly, the Typescript compiler can not extract the type information here.` that is misleading you have not defined the screen and want compiler to identify the other params

Comment: See my update please, is this the desired behavior?